# Boton no redirecciona a otra ventana

Tags: java, android, android-studio

Tengo un Boton dentro de un Fragment, este Boton quiero que sea redirigido a otro Fragment (Activity) donde tendre un ListView, pero al momento de darle click se me cierra la app. ¿Alguna solucion?

Me sale este error en el Fragment(Logcat):

```
2021-08-17 21:20:10.631 10882-10882/? E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    Process: com.example.pibeds, PID: 10882
    java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: No view found for id 0x7f080118 (com.example.pibeds:id/nav_host_fragment_container) for fragment corario_chico{eab363c} (93f305dd-c0c9-46d9-94ab-d2425c8f18f8) id=0x7f080118}
        at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentStateManager.createView(FragmentStateManager.java:315)
        at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManager.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:1187)
        at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManager.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:1356)
        at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManager.moveFragmentToExpectedState(FragmentManager.java:1434)
        at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManager.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:1497)
        at androidx.fragment.app.BackStackRecord.executeOps(BackStackRecord.java:447)
        at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManager.executeOps(FragmentManager.java:2169)
        at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManager.executeOpsTogether(FragmentManager.java:1992)
        at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManager.removeRedundantOperationsAndExecute(FragmentManager.java:1947)
        at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManager.execPendingActions(FragmentManager.java:1849)
        at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManager$4.run(FragmentManager.java:413)
        at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:938)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:223)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7656)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:592)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:947)
```

Ventana1.java
De esta ventan quiero redireccionar a una segunda ventana, pero al momento de intentarlo, se me cierra la app.

```
package com.example.pibeds;
import android.os.Bundle;
import androidx.fragment.app.Fragment;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.Button;



public class corario_chico extends Fragment{

    private Button button;

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // Inflate the layout for this fragment
        View view =  inflater.inflate(R.layout.corario_chico, container, false);
        button = view.findViewById(R.id.button);

        button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                MainActivity.fragmentManager.beginTransaction().replace(R.id.nav_host_fragment_container,new corario_chico(), null).commit();

            }
        });

        return view;

    }


}
```

MainActivity.java
Aqui tengo todo, no se si algo se me paso declarar, si me pueden decir en que estoy mal se los agradeceria mucho.

```
package com.example.pibeds;


import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.Menu;


import com.google.android.material.snackbar.Snackbar;
import com.google.android.material.navigation.NavigationView;

import androidx.fragment.app.Fragment;
import androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManager;
import androidx.fragment.app.FragmentTransaction;
import androidx.navigation.NavController;
import androidx.navigation.Navigation;
import androidx.navigation.ui.AppBarConfiguration;
import androidx.navigation.ui.NavigationUI;
import androidx.drawerlayout.widget.DrawerLayout;
import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;

import com.example.pibeds.databinding.ActivityMainBinding;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    public static FragmentManager fragmentManager;

    private AppBarConfiguration mAppBarConfiguration;
    private ActivityMainBinding binding;


    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        binding = ActivityMainBinding.inflate(getLayoutInflater());
        setContentView(binding.getRoot());

        setSupportActionBar(binding.appBarMain.toolbar);



        binding.appBarMain.fab.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                Snackbar.make(view, "Replace with your own action", Snackbar.LENGTH_LONG)
                        .setAction("Action", null).show();
            }
        });

        DrawerLayout drawer = binding.drawerLayout;
        NavigationView navigationView = binding.navView;
        // Passing each menu ID as a set of Ids because each
        // menu should be considered as top level destinations.

        mAppBarConfiguration = new AppBarConfiguration.Builder(
                R.id.nav_home, R.id.corario_grande, R.id.corario_chico)
                .setOpenableLayout(drawer)
                .build();

        NavController navController = Navigation.findNavController(this, R.id.nav_host_fragment_content_main);
        NavigationUI.setupActionBarWithNavController(this, navController, mAppBarConfiguration);
        NavigationUI.setupWithNavController(navigationView, navController);

        navigationView.setItemIconTintList(null);



            fragmentManager = getSupportFragmentManager();

            if(findViewById(R.id.nav_host_fragment_container)!=null){

            if(savedInstanceState!=null)
            {
                return;
            }

            FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction = fragmentManager.beginTransaction();
            corario_chico corario_chico = new corario_chico();
            fragmentTransaction.add(R.id.nav_host_fragment_container, corario_chico, null);
            fragmentTransaction.commit();

        }


    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
        return true;


    }

    @Override
    public boolean onSupportNavigateUp() {


        NavController navController = Navigation.findNavController(this, R.id.nav_host_fragment_content_main);
        return NavigationUI.navigateUp(navController, mAppBarConfiguration)
                || super.onSupportNavigateUp();


    }
}
```

xml
Aqui es donde tengo el boton para redireccionar pero no funciona:(
Aun no se porque

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".corario_chico">

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="@string/button" />


</FrameLayout>
```

Estoy empezando en Android Studio, una disculpa si me equivoque en algo muy sencillo pero esto es nuevo para mi.
Muchas gracias por su ayuda.

Comment: Muestra el código y revisa el id de la vista que intentas referenciar en el archivo `.xml`. El mensaje es claro: no encuentra ninguna vista con ese ID.

Comment: Ya subi el codigo, si ves el error me dices por favor, gracias!

Comment: ¿En qué `.xml` tienes el elemento con id: `nav_host_fragment_container`? ¿Qué hay en tu layout llamado `corario_chico`? Analiza el mensaje de error y revisa los elementos que éste te indica. Si no lo comprendes, agrega esos elementos a la pregunta para revisar.

Comment: Primero, comenta que se ejecuta en tu batón (`MainActivity.etc`). Segundo, pon un `Toast` en ese mismo botón y fíjate si se muestra o si se te crashea la APP.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

De acuerdo a el mensaje de error:

> java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: No view found for id 0x7f080118
> (com.example.pibeds:id/nav_host_fragment_container) for fragment
> corario_chico{eab363c} (93f305dd-c0c9-46d9-94ab-d2425c8f18f8)
> id=0x7f080118}

Este se provoca cuando realizas la transacción, al cargar el Fragment `corario_chico`:

```
MainActivity.fragmentManager.beginTransaction().replace(R.id.nav_host_fragment_container,new corario_chico(), null).commit();
```

El problema indica que en el Fragment  tratas de obtener la referencia de un recurso que no existe, para saber cual es el recurso, abre tu clase generada `R.java` y busca `0x7f080118` , ahí podrás ver el id del recurso que no existe al cargar tu Fragment.

Answer (score 0):

Haz esto y no olvides marcar como respondida si te funciona

```
   button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
              
              Intent i = new Intent(getActivity(), Actividad_donde_vas.class);
              startActivity(i);


        }
    });
```

Comment: Antes de pedir que marquen tu respuesta como aceptada lee [¿Cómo escribo una buena respuesta?](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer) para que sepas como debes de responder

Comment: Aun no me funciona, vere que puedo hacer, gracias por la informacion